# How define properties as foreign keys in models to MVC Codetemplates generate it as FK

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I use EFCodefirst. Most of you know, but the following code is part of MVC3 T4 CodeTemplates in Edit.tt And also in Create.tt of AddView:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
 <#
        if (property.IsForeignKey) {
 #>
        @Html.DropDownList("<#= property.Name #>", String.Empty)
 <#
        } else {
 #>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.<#= property.Name #>)
 <#
        }
 #>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.<#= property.Name #>)
  </div>
```

As you see if the CodeTemplates find a property as a FK generate a DropDownList automatically, but the question is how can define props as a FK? this is my models:

```
public class Artist {

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}


public class Genre {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

}


public class MusicGalleryDB : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

}
```

I expected the Genre in Artist class be a FK and in create view of Artist I can select a Genre in dropdownlist, but the mvc don't generate any dropdownlist in views actually as mvc's view there is not any relation between Genre and Artist. whe I look at the Database tables I see the following:

```
Artist(Id, Name,Genre_Id)
Genre(Id, Title)
```

as you see there is a column name Genre_Id in Artist table that is a FK to Id of Genre Table This table is generated automatically with EFCodefirst but the MVC CodeTemplate can not recognize FKs.

How can I do this?

I know I can write my own views but I am interesting to mvc generate views automatically in correct way. Does anyone know about this?

**Edit**:

This is my controller (generated automatically by mvc):

```
 public class ArtistController : Controller
{
    private MusicGalleryDB db = new MusicGalleryDB();

    //
    // GET: /Artist/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var artists = db.Artists.Include(a => a.Genre);
        return View(artists.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Artist/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Artist artist = db.Artists.Find(id);
        return View(artist);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Artist/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "Title");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Artist/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Artist artist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Artists.Add(artist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "Title", artist.GenreID);
        return View(artist);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Artist/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Artist artist = db.Artists.Find(id);
        ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "Title", artist.GenreID);
        return View(artist);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Artist/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Artist artist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(artist).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "Title", artist.GenreID);
        return View(artist);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Artist/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Artist artist = db.Artists.Find(id);
        return View(artist);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Artist/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Artist artist = db.Artists.Find(id);
        db.Artists.Remove(artist);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten to include the `GenreID` property in the `Artist` table. Update it to following.

```
public class Artist 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; } // You forgot this
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

BTW, you dont need to use `long`, `int` is good enough for `Id`.

Comment: Thank you Pankja, there is another similar question here about n-n relations maybe you can help me I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227124/how-model-n-n-relationship-in-ef-code-first-to-automatically-generated-views-wo

Comment: I realize that in the detials view of the Artist the Genre field is empty, do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: Have the changed the Id types in both ?? Try changing them or you can just make the GenreId in Artist class of type `long`, rather than `int`. Basically, they should match each others type

Comment: I defined All IDs as int, the problem is not because of that.

Comment: That casn't be possible, because Artist model expects a value for GenreID and will throw the error if not given. You can create the database again using the EF. In case you are having an .sdf file, delete it and the EF will create the same for you again

Comment: I haven't any file with .sdf extension, I search all of Project folder also, but I remove DB, Controllers & views and rebuild it again, but not work yet. and for insurance this is a part of Artist Detials view `<div class="display-field">` `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre.Title)`

Comment: Are other properties for the artist showing the way they are. Can you please add the code for your controller. So that we can see what are you passing to the view.

Comment: yes, all the props (just name) work correctly I edit the Main Question and add controller at all.

Comment: In details action you haven't made the use of include in your query for including the corresponding Genre. Just replace `db.Artists.Find(id)` with `db.Artists.Include("Genre").Where( a => a.Id == id)`

Comment: Updhyay there is two points first: I am interesting in generate views and controllers automatically, is there any way? and Second when replace your suggestion code the expected error appear: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ModelFKinEFCodefirst.Models.Artist>' to 'ModelFKinEFCodefirst.Models.Artist'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Just add `.SingleOrDefault()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end of your query and it will surely work....Second views are always automatically dynamically generated according to the data supplied. As far controller are concerned, i am not sure there is a way to do so