# ASP.NET MVC How Automatically Generate Views With 'N to one' Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I ask a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227124/how-model-n-n-relationship-in-ef-code-first-to-automatically-generated-views-wo) but this is another problem about same point, assume we have the following models:

```
public class Genre {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

}


public class Artist {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> GenreID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}


public class MusicNtoOneDB : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

I am interesting each Artist can have one or some Genres, with EFCodefirst the DB is similar to:

[image]

but in automatically generated views are not any relationship between Artist and Genre, for example I expected to **create** views of Artist can select Genres for new Artist, Is there any way to implement it? I aware about that we can implement views by hand but I am interesting in automatically generated views have been relation between Genre and Artist

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman shows some of Mvc Scaffolding features including model relationships on 
http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix/mix11/key01#time=0h40m45s
you may find it useful

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it can do it for N:M relationships (as torm showed, it is possible at least for 1:N relationships if you download the new MVC 3 tools version from NuGet).

N:M relationships, are quite tricky. What you can do if you have many relationships like this is to create an HTMLHelper or a Partial view which will take a navigation property (let's say a=>a.Genres) and create list which will allow for changes in the mapping (in this case, adding a match with a new Genre or deleting an existing one).